# jq - how to convert an array to a comma separated list of strings in a .gitlab-ci.yml file

Tags: gitlab, jq

I am trying to achieve with jq a conversion from this input:

```
    [
         "10.149.46",
         "10.149.35",
         "10.149.45"
       ]
```

to something like a list of strings, see below:

```
"10.149.46","10.149.35","10.149.45"
```

As I am trying to achieve this and store it in a variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml` to be honest any alternative will be appreciated, not necessarily using `jq`

For more clarity...

Values are stored in a file `sourcefile.json` and under the field `myfield` in a format like:

```
  {
  "myfield": [
         "10.149.46",
         "10.149.35",
         "10.149.45"
  ],
  "otherfield": "othervalue"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? JQ's man page lists a filter to perform JSON-to-CSV conversiond

Comment: @oguzismail an example would be really helpful

Comment: I think `@csv` is what you mean, right? I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

Figured out and thanks @oguzismail for pointing on the right direction

here are the two ways that worked for me:

- with `jq @csv`:

```
> echo $(jq -r '.myfield' sourcefile.json |jq @csv)

result:

"\"10.149.46\",\"10.149.35\",\"10.149.45\""
```

OR

- with `jq tostring`:

```
> echo $(jq -r '.myfield' sourcefile.json |jq tostring)

result:

"[\"10.149.46\",\"10.149.35\",\"10.149.35\"]"
```